# unrecognized url that has method permitAll() and access to login page (redirect loop in login page)

Tags: spring, spring-security

My application has an error that it cannot recognize the url and then give me wrong method I wanted, this make a redirect loop and I can't access to the logig page. Can you help me this?

This is the login page (after I comment the line .anyRequest.authenticated())

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUddk.png)

But in console it appears this:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Rdd.png)

If I uncomment the line .anyRequest.authenticated(), I get into a redirect loop too login page because the login page need to be authenticated to access. This is my code in SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http

                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())

                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login**", "/authentication**", "/authentication/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().anonymous()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/authentication/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                        .failureUrl("/authentication/login?error")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .loginPage("/authentication/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home"))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/home")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

My LoginController.java :

```
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage(){
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String welcomePage(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String password){
        if(userId.equals("admin")&&password.equals("root")){
            model.put("userId",userId);
            return "welcome";
        }
        model.put("errorMsg","please provide the correct user and password");
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/authentication/login?error")
    public String failLogin(ModelMap model){
        model.put("errorMsg","Something errors, please login again!");
        return"login";
    }

}
```

In application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

The hirachy:
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzSOP.png)

If I use withDefault() in formLogin(), there will be no error. Also tried with authorizeHttpRequest() but nothing change.

Fixed it!

By checking the import form CSS url and allow them to pass the authentication, it worked!

```
.requestMatchers("/home","https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/**","https://getbootstrap.com/**").permitAll()
```